# Cannot insert simple table from procedure into declared table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, declaration

i want to put this in to a temp table WITHOUT creating one

```
        declare @table2 table(ID int, Name varchar(300))
        insert @table2
        EXEC dbo.dinoalltime_get
```

error: an insert exec statement cannot be nested

here is my table that the procedure gives:
[image]

i want @table2 to to have whats in the procedure.  so then i can easily say:
        select * from @table2 or pick a necessary column.

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-8164.aspx

Comment: https://suxstellino.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/avoid-nested-insert-exec-where-possible/

Comment: Can you show what is in `dbo.dinoalltime_get`? Why don't you use a view?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
declare @table2 table(ID int, Name varchar(300))
insert into @table2
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;','set fmtonly off EXEC dbo.dinoalltime_get')
```

Answer (score 0):

stored procedure dbo.dinoalltime_get also has insert-exec  statement so it can't be nested.Rewrite your code in current stored procedure or user table value function instead of dbo.dinoalltime_get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OPENROWSET` function to retrieve data from your stored proc something like this:

```
--replace ServerName and DatabaseName
SELECT *
INTO #Table2
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 
'EXEC SERVERNAME.DATABASENAME.dbo.dinoalltime_get')


-- Select Table
SELECT *
FROM #Table2;
```

You can use this query to find your provider (for e.g. SQLNCLI) and servername :

```
select * from sys.servers
```

Courtesy of [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-how-to-insert-data-from-stored-procedure-to-table-2-different-methods/)